# Coffeescript, external file and Inheritance

Tags: node.js, inheritance, coffeescript

Sorry about my english grammar.

I am written a simple BROWSER based script with Coffeescript.
but things start to get too messy and now I want to separete my classes on different files, to be more organized.

I just need to know how I make something like the require of PHP.

I got node plus coffee watching my files and compiling everytime I save my files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `require.js` to load and organize your script files.

Once you are in production, you can use `r.js` to compile your client side project (coffee to js) and minify it to one single file.

Comment: require.js can be a bit challenging if you're just beginning. You can also import them via the script tag and use a document.ready wrapper. Then, you just use them as if they ARE there. Also, if you're comfortable with node.js (which is essentially javascript), you might like using its require function, it's a lot easier than working with require.js/ r.js/ almond.js